# how to send two or more separate result for ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to know how can I send two separate result to ajax j Query success
php file:

```
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbCnn)== -1)
       echo "Failed";
    else
      echo "Success" ;   
    include('table.php');
```

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: $(this).serialize() + '&' + ids + '=' + 'submit',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#tableContainer").html(data);
    }
});
```

I want to have to data, one for echo "Success" for example, and one for include table.php .

Comment: Send a JSON response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could serialize them in json:

In your php:

```
ob_start();
include('table.php');
$table = ob_get_clean();
echo json_encode(array('table' => $table, 'message' => 'success'));
```

In javascript change as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: $(this).serialize()+ '&' + ids + '=' + 'submit',
    success: function(response){
        $("#tableContainer").html(response.table);
        alert(response.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a formatted response, in which you detail result1, result2,... resultx.
Nowadays, most people would use JSON in order to format and send data. But you could also use XML or define your own.

`JSON` example:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "results": {
    "connection": true,
    "table": false
  }
}
```

Dazu kann in PHP die Funktion `json_encode()` verwendet werden:

```
json_encode([
  'status' => 'ok',
  'results' => array(
    'connection' => $result1,
    'table' => $result2
  )
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not so far. And Has I can see you're not asking for json.
Anyway just to tell you, you don't need the word **success** to call success in your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'post',
    data: $(this).serialize() + '&' + ids + '=' + 'submit',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#tableContainer").html(data);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbCnn)== -1){
   echo "Failed";
} else {
   echo "Success";
   include('table.php');
}
```